# NFSv4 with Kerberos takes a long time to mount

Tags: linux, nfs, kerberos, nfs4, mitkerberos

I have an NFS server with Kerberos authentication (Debian 11). If I want to mount a share on a client for the first time after a restart, this takes 10-12 seconds. If I then mount another share from the same server, it works almost immediately.

NFS exports:

```
/data/bilder    192.168.1.0/24(sec=krb5p,rw,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,root_squash,no_all_squash)
/data/video    192.168.1.0/24(sec=krb5p,rw,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,root_squash,no_all_squash)
/data/musik    192.168.1.0/24(sec=krb5p,rw,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

/etc/default/nfs-common:

```
# If you do not set values for the NEED_ options, they will be attempted
# autodetected; this should be sufficient for most people. Valid alternatives
# for the NEED_ options are "yes" and "no".

# Do you want to start the statd daemon? It is not needed for NFSv4.
NEED_STATD=

# Options for rpc.statd.
#   Should rpc.statd listen on a specific port? This is especially useful
#   when you have a port-based firewall. To use a fixed port, set this
#   this variable to a statd argument like: "--port 4000 --outgoing-port 4001".
#   For more information, see rpc.statd(8) or http://wiki.debian.org/SecuringNFS
STATDOPTS=

# Do you want to start the idmapd daemon? It is only needed for NFSv4.
NEED_IDMAPD=yes

# Do you want to start the gssd daemon? It is required for Kerberos mounts.
NEED_GSSD=yes
```

/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server:

```
# Number of servers to start up
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8

# Runtime priority of server (see nice(1))
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0

# Options for rpc.mountd.
# If you have a port-based firewall, you might want to set up
# a fixed port here using the --port option. For more information, 
# see rpc.mountd(8) or http://wiki.debian.org/SecuringNFS
# To disable NFSv4 on the server, specify '--no-nfs-version 4' here
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"

# Do you want to start the svcgssd daemon? It is only required for Kerberos
# exports. Valid alternatives are "yes" and "no"; the default is "no".
NEED_SVCGSSD="yes"

# Options for rpc.svcgssd.
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=""
```

krb5.conf (client and server):

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = TS13.LAN
    allow_weak_crypto = false
    rdns = false
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    TS13.LAN = {
        kdc = dc.ts13.lan
                admin_server = dc.ts13.lan
    }

[domain_realm]
        .ts13.lan = TS13.LAN
        ts13.lan = TS13.LAN
```

kdc.conf:

```
[kdcdefaults]
    kdc_ports = 88
    restrict_anonymous_to_tgt = true
    spake_preauth_kdc_challenge = edwards25519

[realms]
    TS13.LAN = {
        database_name = /var/lib/krb5kdc/principal
        admin_keytab = FILE:/etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
        acl_file = /etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
        key_stash_file = /etc/krb5kdc/stash
        kdc_ports = 88
        max_life = 10h 0m 0s
        max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
        master_key_type = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
        supported_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96:normal aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96:normal
        default_principal_flags = +preauth
        spake_preauth_indicator = hardened
        encrypted_challenge_indicator = hardened
    }
```

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: my question is why it needs solage